# OpenCV Mat causes Crash with SIGABRT

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu

I'm testing the Mat class functionalities by creating a 50x50 single channel matrix which, once displayed, should results in a black picture. Unfortunately, my program crashes at line 3 of the following code:

```
cv::Mat projImg = cv::Mat::zeros(50, 50, CV_8U);
cv::namedWindow( "Test");
cv::imshow("Test", projImg);
```

with the error **The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system. Signal name: SIGABRT**. This is quite strange for because this code is incredibly simple.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit with Qt 4.0.2.

n.b. i get the same error even if projImg is set as a regular image

```
cv::Mat projImg = cv::imread("/home/is/Downloads/test.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your basic `OpenCV` functionality is faulty. So it may be the case that your `OpenCV` is not configured to be built with `Qt` support.
Checklist:

1. Eliminate all `highgui` methods to ensure that the core `OpenCV` tools work fine. You can replace the `namedWindow` and `imshow` with `imwrite`.
2. Check your `OpenCV` build procedure again and look for specific `Qt` options. If you are using `CMake`, look for `With Qt` toggle and related `Qt` paths.

Comment: All opencv functions i've tried so far are working fine (e.g. imread, imwrite, conversions such as cvtColor and so on). Apparently I have problems exclusively with imshow.
As for my OpenCV build procedured, i've followed the instructions suggested on the Qt website https://wiki.qt.io/OpenCV_with_Qt

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. The simple answer is - use the Qt calls for event handling and drawing images. It's relatively simple to display the CV matrix to the Qt screen.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    if (argc != 2)
        return  -1;

    MyWindow w{};
    w.loadImage(argv[1]);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}



void MyWindow::loadImage(const char *path)
{
    m_img  = cv::imread(path, 1);
    cv::cvtColor(m_img, m_img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);    
}


void MyWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
{
    QPainter painter{this};
    if (m_img.data)
    {
        QImage img{m_img.data, m_img.cols, m_img.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888};
        painter.drawImage(QRectF(0, 0, 300, 300), img);
    }
}
```

I am still having some artifacts, since I was not investigating in deep, but you have to play with the pixelformat to find the answers. Otherwise, this will display the thing to Qt from the cv::Mat object.